# How to make an efficient notification generator using php jquery

Tags: php, jquery, database-design, notifications

I am working on something smalland was thinking of making a good notification generator like facebook does Mainly I want how the the tables might look. How to make updates and all the nessecities and cautions i should have Thanks

I have users as they upload images comment like a persons profile I want the person whose post was like commented or any other action  to be notified that this person likes your photo

The way Facebook does it

Comment: please get more information about you would like to do, it is not really clear from you description.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind can u help me now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to do it, one of which is to have a column in the table titled `new_notification` that will tell you if the notification is new(read by the user or not). So, for example, if a person likes another persons picture, in the table that column will have `new_notification` set to `Y`. When the user who's picture was liked logs into the website, you search for all rows where `new_notification = Y` do a count and show the number of notifications like facebook does. Once the user has seen the notifications or opened the notification bar, go through that table and set all the rows with `new_notification = Y` to `'N'`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes I agree with @Interstellar_Coder, you could have your post page info stored in one line in a database table, and your like info stored in another table.  Reference which picture the person likes by ID.

Table 1 (picture posts):

```
ID | Picture    | Comments   | who
1  | (pic data) | my picture | user.name_1
```

Table 2 (likes):

```
row_ID | picture_ID | who
0      | 1          | user.name_2
1      | 1          | user.name_3
```

So in this example you have 1 picture posted by user.name_1, then this picture has been liked by user.name_2 and user.name_3.  We know this because of the picture_ID field in the `likes` table.

You can check in your database who likes picture post with ID=1, and it will tell you who likes it, mysql code example:

```
select who from likes where picture_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Nice one too how far in can u guys be with all this nice stuff

Comment: what do you mean?  "How far in" can we be?

Comment: You know a lot and I wanted to know what you have done with you knowledgeable mindset

Comment: Oh, OK.  Well i am a programmer and I build data basing applications for a living.  So i think about problems like this every day.  There are basic tools for most of these data applications, like obviously... the database.  The point of the database is to store all relevant information in an organized and coherent manner.  There is no one way to do anything, and some ways are better than others.  That is why stackoverflow is so cool, you can see how other people do things and compare, argue, discuss etc. I see this is your first post, if you like something give it a +1, if correct, check mark!

Comment: hope I could have a life with programming too am so in to it!